# Falha ao carregar Resouces de um Resource File

Tags: xamarin, uwp

Estou tentando fazer minha aplicação Xamarin ser internacionalizável.
Segui o tutorial (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) que funciona no Android, porém, quando testo no windows é estourada a exceção `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException`.
Mais especificamente

```
An exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load resources for resource file "Projeto.Resources.AppResources" in package "df348a55-72cd-4de3-a7db-cb0ecacf1e0b".
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Obs1: Existem dois arquivos de RESX (AppResources.resx e AppResources.es.resx) em uma PCL que esta referenciada no projeto UWP.
Obs2: Na `TranslateExtension` ao envés de eu usar

```
ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                            , typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

estou usando

```
ResourceManager resmgr = AppResources.ResourceManager;
```

Comment: Qual linha o erro ocorre (coloque na pergunta se possível)? Qual a versão do `xamarin`?. Sua `UI` é via código ou `XAML`?